# Conditional BizTalk mapping for equivalent nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I am trying to do a BizTalk map with some kind of looping over `LoopingNode`, where if `Cond1` is false, create `Type1`. If `Cond1` is true then create `Type2`. It looks like this:

Input:

```
root
   - LoopingNode
        - id (string)
        - Cond1 (bool)
```

Output:

```
root
   - TargetNode
        <Equivalent>
           - Type1
                - id (string)
           - Type2
                - id (string)
```

And the output should look something like this

```
<root>
    <TargetNode type="Type2" id="a" />
    <TargetNode type="Type1" id="q" />
</root>
```

I have tried with 2 table loopings with column 1 as gate, but that didn't work. And my recent attempt was to do a value mapping with cond as a condition. The generated xslt became this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">
  <xsl:value-of select="'ns0:Type1'" />
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:if test="string($var:v6)='true'">
  <xsl:variable name="var:v7" select="string(s1:Id/text())" />
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="$var:v7" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">
  <xsl:value-of select="'ns0:Type2'" />
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:if test="string($var:v6)='false'">
  <xsl:variable name="var:v10" select="string(s1:Id/text())" />
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="$var:v10" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

And since the `xsl:if` only surrounds the id-tag and not the `<xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">` tag, the value will always be `Type2` since that is last in the xslt.

I rather have a non-custom xslt solution but maybe that isn't possible. The real issue is much more complex than this (around 20 more attributes, 3 equivalent types and 2 conditions). But the solution should probably be the same.

Any ideas how to do a conditional looping over equivalent nodes?

**UPDATE:**
Here is an schema (xsd) that corresponds to my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns="http://demo.com/schema/" targetNamespace="http://demo.com/schema/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <xs:element name="root" type ="Root">
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="Root">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="TargetNode" type="TargetNode" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>  
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TargetNode" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Type1">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TargetNode">
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Type2">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TargetNode">
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for conditional looping.  The map should have:

- Direct links between the `id` nodes
- A looping functoid going from the `LoopingNode` the `TargetNode`
- Logical functoids to do conditional looping based on `Cond1` and outputting to `Type1` and `Type2`

That'd look something like this:

[image]

Where those logical functoids have configuration like this:

[image: Functoid config]

Both can have the same config if you use equals and not equals - or use two equals and set Condition2 to false in one of them.

You can read more about conditional looping at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561739.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Based on this XML input:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalk_Server_Project1.Schema1">
    <LoopingNode Cond1="true" id="id_0"/>
    <LoopingNode Cond1="true" id="id_1"/>
    <LoopingNode Cond1="false" id="id_2"/>
    <LoopingNode Cond1="true" id="id_3"/>
</ns0:Root>
```

I get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:root xmlns:ns0="http://demo.com/schema/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ns0:TargetNode id="id_0" xsi:type="ns0:Type1"/>
  <ns0:TargetNode id="id_1" xsi:type="ns0:Type1"/>
  <ns0:TargetNode id="id_2" xsi:type="ns0:Type2"/>
  <ns0:TargetNode id="id_3" xsi:type="ns0:Type1"/>
</ns0:root>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. You made the Target schema too simple (great answer with pictures though). I have updated the question with an example of the target schema file.

Comment: Your updated schema is significantly different from how I understood the initial question, but I think the general approach should still work.  I can update the answer...

Comment: Updated - does that help?

Comment: Yup, that worked. Fantastic solution. Didn't even know you could do this. Thanks!